# Find first use of particular word in string & then display image url which is exacly after it(VB.Net)

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string which consists of the raw HTML of a webpage. I would like to search for the first use of **/imgres?imgurl=** within the string and display the url of an image which follows exactly after it in a text box. Below is an example of part of the string:

href="/imgres?imgurl=http://www.pic.com/pic.jpg&imgrefurl=http

In this case it would find /imgres?imgurl= then it would display http://www.pic.com/pic.jpg in a text box.

Please note /imgres?imgurl= appears about 20 times in the string, I only would like first use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bother with reg ex.

If you already have a string just do something like:

```
Dim myString as String = "my long html text...."

Dim start as Int32 = myString.IndexOf("/imgres?imgurl=")

myString = myString.Substring(start + 15)

Dim end as Int32 = myString.IndexOf("&imgref")

myString = myString.Substring(0, end)
```

This can be heavily optimized but it should point you in the right direction

Comment: @Daren: btw, remember to click the little check mark next to the answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess ... `/imgres?imgurl=(.+?)&`